# Clear Input Field on button click

Tags: javascript, html

cant get my input fields to clear when clear scorecard button is clicked.

put onclick function. even if it when my page refreshes the input fields clear. I understand there may be a better way of presenting the code in my JS file however i just want to get the fundamentals correct before changing.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>My Golf Tracker</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Main Navigation Menu-->
        <div id="main-nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="nav-li"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-li"><a href="#">History</a></li>
            <li class="nav-li"><a href="#">Stats</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h1 id="main-header">
                My Golf Tracker
            </h1>
            <!--STATS-->
        <div class="stats">
            <h1>Round Stats</h1>
            <p>Gross Score:</p><input id="gross-score"></input>
            <p>Nett Score:</p><input id="nett-score"></input>
            <p>Stableford Score:</p><input id="stableford-score"></input>
            <p>Total Putts:</p><input id="total-putts"></input>
            <br>
            <button type="save" id="save">Save Round</button>
        </div>

        </div>

        <!--Selection of Golf Course-->
        <div class="selections">
        Select Golf Course
        <select id="course-select" >
            <option>Penn Golf Club</option>
            <option>Perton Park</option>
        </select>
        </div>

        <!--Selection which Tees-->
        <div class="selections">Select Tee's
            <select id="tee-select">
            <option id="white">White</option>
            <option id="yellow">Yellow</option>
        </select>

    </div>
        <!--handicap Input-->
        <div class="selections">Handicap
            <input id="handicap" placeholder="Enter">
        </input>
    </div>
        <!--Date of Round Select-->
    <div class="selections"> Select Date
        <input type="date" id="date-select"></select>
    </div>


    <!--HOLES-->
    <div class="container">
    <article class="front9">
            <div class="hole">
                <span>Front</span>
                <span>1</span>
                <span>2</span>
                <span>3</span>
                <span>4</span>
                <span>5</span>
                <span>6</span>
                <span>7</span>
                <span>8</span>
                <span>9</span>
                <span>Out</span>

            </div>

            <!--Hole PAR -->
            <div class="par">
                <span>Par</span>
                <span>4</span>
                <span>4</span>
                <span>4</span>
                <span>5</span>
                <span>4</span>
                <span>4</span>
                <span>3</span>
                <span>4</span>
                <span>3</span>
                <span>35</span>
            </div>


            <!-- Stroke Index -->
            <div class="stroke-index">
                <span>Index</span>
                <span>9</span>
                <span>13</span>
                <span>3</span>
                <span>15</span>
                <span>7</span>
                <span>5</span>
                <span>17</span>
                <span>1</span>
                <span>11</span>
                <span>35</span>
            </div>

            <!--Hole SCORE -->
            <div class="score">
                <span>Score</span>
                <input id="f1" value=""></input>
                <input id="f2" value=""></input>
                <input id="f3" value=""></input>
                <input id="f4" value=""></input>
                <input id="f5" value=""></input>
                <input id="f6" value=""></input>
                <input id="f7" value=""></input>
                <input id="f8" value=""></input>
                <input id="f9" value=""></input>
                <input id="front-nine"></input>

            </div>

            <!---Putts Made-->

            <div class="putts">
                    <span>Putts</span>
                    <input id="p1" value=""></input>
                    <input id="p2" value=""></input>
                    <input id="p3" value=""></input>
                    <input id="p4" value=""></input>
                    <input id="p5" value=""></input>
                    <input id="p6" value=""></input>
                    <input id="p7" value=""></input>
                    <input id="p8" value=""></input>
                    <input id="p9" value=""></input>       
                </div>
            </div>   
        </article>

        <!--Back 9-->
        <div class="container">
        <article class="back9">
            <div class="hole">
                <span>Back</span>
                <span>10</span>
                <span>11</span>
                <span>12</span>
                <span>13</span>
                <span>14</span>
                <span>15</span>
                <span>16</span>
                <span>17</span>
                <span>18</span>
                <span>In</span>

            </div>

            <!--Hole PAR -->
            <div class="par">
                <span>Par</span>
                <span>5</span>
                <span>3</span>
                <span>4</span>
                <span>3</span>
                <span>5</span>
                <span>4</span>
                <span>4</span>
                <span>3</span>
                <span>5</span>
                <span>35</span>

            </div>

            <!--Stroke Index-->
            <div class="stroke-index">
                <span>Index</span>
                <span>12</span>
                <span>18</span>
                <span>2</span>
                <span>16</span>
                <span>4</span>
                <span>8</span>
                <span>14</span>
                <span>6</span>
                <span>10</span>
                <span>35</span>
            </div>

            <!--Score Back 9-->
            <div class="score">
                <span>Score</span>
                <input id="b1" value=""></input>
                <input id="b2" value=""></input>
                <input id="b3" value=""></input>
                <input id="b4" value=""></input>
                <input id="b5" value=""></input>
                <input id="b6" value=""></input>
                <input id="b7" value=""></input>
                <input id="b8" value=""></input>
                <input id="b9" value=""></input>
                <input id="back-nine"></input>
            </div>

            <!--Putts Back 9-->
            <div class="putts">
                    <span>Putts</span>
                    <input id="p10" value=""></input>
                    <input id="p11" value=""></input>
                    <input id="p12" value=""></input>
                    <input id="p13" value=""></input>
                    <input id="p14" value=""></input>
                    <input id="p15" value=""></input>
                    <input id="p16" value=""></input>
                    <input id="p17" value=""></input> 
                    <input id="p18" value=""></input>
                </div>


            <button type="submit" id="submit-score" onclick="grossScore()">Submit Score</button>
            <button value="0" onclick="clearInp();">Clear Scorecard</button>


    </body>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    </html>

  function grossScore() {
    const holeOne = parseInt(document.querySelector("#f1").value);
    const holeTwo = parseInt(document.querySelector("#f2").value);
    const holeThree = parseInt(document.querySelector("#f3").value);
    const holeFour = parseInt(document.querySelector("#f4").value);
    const holeFive = parseInt(document.querySelector("#f5").value);
    const holeSix = parseInt(document.querySelector("#f6").value);
    const holeSeven = parseInt(document.querySelector("#f7").value);
    const holeEight = parseInt(document.querySelector("#f8").value);
    const holeNine = parseInt(document.querySelector("#f9").value);
    const holeTen = parseInt(document.querySelector("#b1").value);
    const holeEleven = parseInt(document.querySelector("#b2").value);
    const holeTwelve = parseInt(document.querySelector("#b3").value);
    const holeThirteen = parseInt(document.querySelector("#b4").value);
    const holeFourteen = parseInt(document.querySelector("#b5").value);
    const holeFifteen = parseInt(document.querySelector("#b6").value);
    const holeSixteen = parseInt(document.querySelector("#b7").value);
    const holeSeventeen = parseInt(document.querySelector("#b8").value);
    const holeEighteen = parseInt(document.querySelector("#b9").value);
    const handicap = parseInt(document.querySelector("#handicap").value);

    const one = parseInt(document.querySelector("#p1").value);
    const two = parseInt(document.querySelector("#p2").value);
    const three = parseInt(document.querySelector("#p3").value);
    const four = parseInt(document.querySelector("#p4").value);
    const five = parseInt(document.querySelector("#p5").value);
    const six = parseInt(document.querySelector("#p6").value);
    const seven = parseInt(document.querySelector("#p7").value);
    const eight = parseInt(document.querySelector("#p8").value);
    const nine = parseInt(document.querySelector("#p9").value);
    const ten = parseInt(document.querySelector("#p10").value);
    const eleven = parseInt(document.querySelector("#p11").value);
    const twelve = parseInt(document.querySelector("#p12").value);
    const thirteen = parseInt(document.querySelector("#p13").value);
    const fourteen = parseInt(document.querySelector("#p14").value);
    const fifteen = parseInt(document.querySelector("#p15").value);
    const sixteen = parseInt(document.querySelector("#p16").value);
    const seventeen = parseInt(document.querySelector("#p17").value);
    const eighteen = parseInt(document.querySelector("#p18").value);

    document.getElementById("gross-score").value =
      holeOne +
      holeTwo +
      holeThree +
      holeFour +
      holeFive +
      holeSix +
      holeSeven +
      holeEight +
      holeNine +
      holeTen +
      holeEleven +
      holeTwelve +
      holeThirteen +
      holeFourteen +
      holeFifteen +
      holeSixteen +
      holeSeventeen +
      holeEighteen;

    document.getElementById("nett-score").value =
      document.getElementById("gross-score").value - handicap;

    document.getElementById("total-putts").value =
      one +
      two +
      three +
      four +
      five +
      six +
      seven +
      eight +
      nine +
      ten +
      eleven +
      twelve +
      thirteen +
      fourteen +
      fifteen +
      sixteen +
      seventeen +
      eighteen;

      document.getElementById("front-nine").value =
      holeOne +
      holeTwo +
      holeThree +
      holeFour +
      holeFive +
      holeSix +
      holeSeven +
      holeEight +
      holeNine

      document.getElementById("back-nine").value =
      holeTen +
      holeEleven +
      holeTwelve +
      holeThirteen +
      holeFourteen +
      holeFifteen +
      holeSixteen +
      holeSeventeen +
      holeEighteen;



  }

  function clearInp() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("input").value = "";
    }
```

All my input fields clear

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("input")` return array.

Comment: `<button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>` this will reset all input fields

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Comment: And the default `type` for `button` is still `submit`, so this will still submit your form. You need to either cancel the default action in your click event handler - or explicitly add `type="button"` to the button, to make it a “click button”, and not automatically send the form.

Comment: You should also look into arrays. For instance `var holes = [4, 5, 3];` creates an array where `holes[0]` is `4`. This will dramatically reduce these tons of repetitive code.

Comment: yes Chris i know, i will go with the arrays option later, im currently new to html and javascript 3 weeks in :).

Comment: @JamesHillman, first give form open and close tag, then your code also will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your reset function, you have to loop through every element with tag `input` and set their values to nothing as below

```
function clearInp() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].value = "";
  }
}
```